# C# Do I have to unsubscribe from WMI events before closing?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, event-handling, wmi-query

As the title says, In my code I have registered a callback function when a program launches using WMI:

```
ManagementEventWatcher Watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStartTrace WHERE ProcessName='ExampleApp.exe'"));
```

Before my application exits do I have to call:

```
Watcher.Stop(); 
Watcher.Dispose();
```

Or is it done automatically. The reason I ask is that my application that is subscribing to the event will be `Process.Kill()` by another application, rather than gracefully terminating so it doesn't not have the chance to properly unsubscribe.

Thanks

Comment: While that is done automatically by the GC (AFAIK), it won't be near as fast as if you did it yourself. You should not be closing your app with `Process.Kill()` though

Comment: Nothing goes wrong if you don't Stop or Dispose.  The OS always cleans up correctly.  It is its job.

Comment: You should only ask one question per post. If you have a new question post a new question.